Require two fields to have the same value in JSON Schema
I need two different fields in my JSON Schema to have the same value. The validation should fail whenever the two values are different. Is this possible using only JSON Schema?

This question is similar to: Can JSON Schema require one value equal another?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If your JSON validator supports the $data keyword then you can enforce that two fields match each other, regardless of what that value actually is.
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "field1": { "type": "string" },
    "field2": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "required": [ "field1", "field2" ],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "field1": { "const": { "$data": "1/field2"  } }
      }
    }
  ]
}


The $data keyword is incompatible with JSON Schema as it produces invalid schemas.  It is not defined by the spec and we've pushed to get implementations to stop supporting any form of it.

Yes I've started my answer with "if your JSON validator supports the $data keyword".

What I'm saying is that JSON Schema (the org/spec, for which I can speak) doesn't support this keyword.  All iterations of the proposal have been rejected because it produces invalid schemas.  For example, minimum: { $data: "#/foo/bar" } doesn't work because minimum expects a number, and it got an object.  The keyword should be avoided.

Sure, you can use const.
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "one": {
            "const": "same_value"
        },
        "two": {
            "const": "same_value"
        }
    }
}


The value should be variable so the user can choose any string, but if the two fields are different, then the schema validation fails. Would it be possible?

JSON Schema doesn't have any way to compare values across properties
